# Angular 2 refresh views on local storage's value change

Tags: javascript, angular, store

I have a navbar that prints out the name and the surname of the user. Both these variables are taken from the local storage on component init. 
I have a modal, in the modal I can change the name and surname of the logged user and put them again in the local storage. If I change them successfully I want to update the navbar with the new name and surname.

The modal and the navbar are two different components.

How can I achieve this?

Solution 1: I was thinking to modify manually the variables while the post of the new data (name and surname) has been successfully executed. 
Can I modify the variables of another component (the navbar) from the modal?

Solution 2: call a location.reload to force updating automatically all the view with the new data in local storage.

Solution 3: using a store

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you already answer your own question with 3 possible solutions? What's the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to a have as many solutions as possibile to choose the one that is best for me. Im not satisfied with mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper service for getting/setting local storage, that will also emit when setting. Modal calls, say, `this.storageService.setItem('foo', 'bar')`, while nav bar has subscribed `this.storageService.changes$`.

While there is an event emitted when something writes to the storage, it only get emitted in other windows for the same domain.

Comment: Could you please provide a small example for this solution, seems like the one I am looking for. I'm a novice with angular 2. Thanks

Comment: It's pretty much it. You create a service (for the general gist, the official Angular tutorial is perfectly adequate) that has two methods: `getItem` and `setItem`, and a property `change$: Subject<{key, value}>`. `getItem` only calls localStorage.getItem, `setItem` calls localStorage.setItem _and_ emits the change to the `change$` stream. You inject your service in the navbar and modal (and everywhere in the app where you use local storage). Navbar subscribes `change$` and updates its display if needed.